# underline with decreasing thickness style

Tags: html, css

Any idea how to implement this decreasing thickness underline using css:
[(Example image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy7Ae.png)

I've tried to use border bottom, but couldn't give the decreasing thickness effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use clip-path property. For more [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: fit-content;
}

p span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

p:after {
  background: orange;
  clip-path: polygon(0 80%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Training & Development</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not just underline or border;

You should use `:before` in CSS and position: `absolute;` on it and `position: relative;` on the parent.

The code would be:

```css
    .underline {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 32px;
    }

    .underline:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
        border-right: 300px solid transparent;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<span class="underline">Training & Development</span>
```

`border-bottom: 5px` <- here you can set the starting height of the underline.

`border-right: 100px` <- here you can set the width of the underline.

Read more about creating shapes in CSS here: https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbhv18ef/